# FAB (Floating Action Button) Overlay in lollipop and higher version

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am developing an application which uses a `FloatingActionButton(FAB)` just like skype or Inbox. onClick of the FAB I am displaying the dialog with the overlayed background.

For the Kitkat version, the whole screen will be overlayed which is fine, but for the lollipop and marshmallow it is overlaying only till the PageViewer and it is not covering the ActionBar(AppBarLayout). I am trying to fix it but I couldn't.

How can I solve this issue?

**Here is the code snippet:**

```
    final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
    frameLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
    final FloatingActionsMenu fabMenu = (FloatingActionsMenu) findViewById(R.id.multiple_actions);
    fabMenu.setOnFloatingActionsMenuUpdateListener(new FloatingActionsMenu.OnFloatingActionsMenuUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuExpanded() {
           frameLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(240);
            frameLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    fabMenu.collapse();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onMenuCollapsed() {
            frameLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
            frameLayout.setOnTouchListener(null);
        }
    });`
```

**And this is the layout:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeBlue">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppThemeBlue"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white_overlay"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end">

<com.support.android.fabbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/white"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
        fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/half_black"
        fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

        <com.support.android.fabbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/action_a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/micro"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
            fab:fab_title="Action A"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed" />

        <com.support.android.fabbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/action_b"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
            fab:fab_title="Action with a very long name "
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>

    </com.support.android.fabbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>
</FrameLayout>
```

This is what i am achieving currently. As you can see the `ActionBar` is not coverd...[image]

Comment: Did you solve this problem ?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. translationZ for overlay view partially solves it (I still can scroll views behind the overlay), but it is only supported since API v21

Answer (score 0):

you have wrapped your fab with frame layout and placed it inside viewpager so it will be shown inside viewpager only ...wrap your xml inside coordinator layout and then check it if it is working ..take frame layout out of view pager

like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeBlue">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppThemeBlue"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


<com.support.android.fabbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/white"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
        fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/half_black"
        fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

        <com.support.android.fabbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/action_a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/micro"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
            fab:fab_title="Action A"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed" />

        <com.support.android.fabbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/action_b"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
            fab:fab_title="Action with a very long name "
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>

    </com.support.android.fabbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: If the frame layout is the problem then how is it working properly for kitkat? And also tried removing it.. but it didnot work..

Comment: Frame layout is not the problem u can keep it but use inside coordinator layout .. check xml i have posted . did you try it ?

Comment: what i mean to say your alpha will be applied to framelayout only which is inside viewpager ..the above two appbar and tablayout are excluded.. change alpha of root(appbarlayout) in your case or change alpha of coordinate layout in my case so you will get desired effect